# Is it possible to form an alloy of gold and zinc?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, metallurgy

I know you can dissolve gold in mercury, but i do not have access to any. Would it be possible to dissolve it in molten zinc instead mercury.

Comment: Of cause, if you melt both metals together you would get an alloy of both.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. [There are alloys and intermetallic compounds up to $\ce{44\%Au:56\%Zn}$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022508879902820).  This phase diagram is from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253702430_Size_effect_on_the_mechanical_properties_in_zinc_oxide).

[image]

That said, crystal structure changes with composition, so appearance on solidification might be hard to predict.

[Are you trying to emulate Hevesy?](https://www.npr.org/sections/krulwich/2011/10/03/140815154/dissolve-my-nobel-prize-fast-a-true-story)

Comment: No, my planned use for this is to process gold too fine to pan from black sand, without using expensive chemicals or mercury.

Comment: Interesting idea... it also avoids use of poisonous Hg. If practical, it might be necessary to blanket in inert gas, as Zn is reactive.

Comment: I not sure, but it will need a fair amount of sulfuric acid to disolve the zinc.   As for a inert gas CO2 should work.

Comment: @Brad not sure about CO2.  Could form CO+ZnO at elevated temp.  N2 is safer.

Answer (score 0):

Gold looks pretty soluble in molten zinc. The melting temperature increases up to about 625 C with 50% gold.Charcoal on the surface of the melt will partly protect the zinc ; I have seen charcoal used on lead but not zinc.